# fluentd バージョンアップでプラグインが使用している Fluent::S3Output が認識されなくなった

Tags: rubygems, fluentd

fluentd によって API サーバーのログを AWS S3 に送信しているシステムで
td-agent 0.12.40 から 1.6.3 にバージョンアップしようと思っています

本体のバージョンアップ自体はおわったのですが
/etc/td-agent/plugin/ にある以下のようなプラグインが

```
module Fluent
  require 'fluent/plugin/out_s3'
  require 'yajl'

  class CustomS3Output < S3Output

    Plugin.register_output('custom_s3', self)

    def write(chunk)
      :
     (略)
      :
    end
  end
end
```

```
/etc/td-agent/plugin/out_s3.rb:9:in `<module:Fluent>': uninitialized constant Fluent::S3Output (NameError)
```

というエラーをはくようになりました

Fluent::S3Output というのは
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3
の
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/out_s3.rb
のことだと思うのですが

```
/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-s3
```

を行ってジェムのインストールには成功したんですがエラーは変わりません

バージョンアップ前はこのままのコードで動作していたので
バージョンアップによってジェムのインストール方法や認識方法がかわったのでしょうか

サイトの最後の方に

```
module Fluent # Since fluent-plugin-s3 v1.0.0 or later, use Fluent::Plugin instead of Fluent
```

とかいてあるので１行目を

```
module Fluent::Plugin
```

と変更してみたんですが

```
/etc/td-agent/plugin/out_s3.rb:11:in `<class:CustomS3Output>': uninitialized constant Fluent::Plugin::CustomS3Output::Plugin (NameError)
```

というエラーになります

原因のわかる方いらっしゃったら助けていただけるとありがたいです
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0):

Fluentdとfluent-plugin-s3のバージョンアップでプラグインのnamespaceが変わったため、エラーになっています。

/etc/td-agent/plugin/ にある custom_s3 を以下のようにすると動くと思います。

```rb
module Fluent
  module Plugin
    class CustomS3Output < Fluent::Plugin::S3Output
      Fluent::Plugin.register_output(self, "custom_s3")
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

プラグインのAPIが変わっているので、これだけだと動かない可能性があります。
その場合は、[ドキュメント](https://docs.fluentd.org/plugin-development/plugin-update-from-v0.12)を参考にcustom_s3もv1のAPIを使うようにしてください。
あと、改造内容によっては新しいバージョンのfluent-plugin-s3でそのまま対応できるかもしれないので、調べてみてください。